# Retrieving Deny Access Group members from names.nsf directory

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am using Lotus Notes version 8.5.2.. I am relatively new to lotus.domino java API's. I need to retrieve the members within Deny Access Group and put it into a file.How do i go about accessing the members using API's provided..? Any help in this regard is appreciated..

I have come up with following code from what i could make out of the reply..Let me know if i'm heading in right direction.

```
lotus.domino.Document fDoc = null;
lotus.domino.Database fDb = null;
lotus.domino.View view = null;

fDb = NotesSess.getDatabase(sServerName, "names.nsf");
view = fDb.getView("DenyLists");
fDoc = view.getFirstDocument();
 while(fDoc != null)
   {
      java.util.Vector fItems = fDoc.getItems();
      for(int iCnt=0 ; iCnt < fItems.size();iCnt++)
          {
            lotus.domino.Item fItem = (Item) fItems.elementAt(iCnt);
                 if(fItem.getName()== "Members")
                      {
                         Vector fItemValues = fItem.getValues();
                         int fNumValues = fItemValues.size();
                         String fValueStr = null ;
                         for(int ii=0 ;ii < fNumValues ;ii++)
                           fValueStr = (String) fItemValues.elementAt(ii);
                        }
            }
    }
```

Will i be getting the members in variable `fValueStr`?

Comment: That looks like an infinite loop. Do you have one or many Deny Access Groups? Use fDoc.getItemValue("Members") to get the members to a Vector.

Comment: I have only one Deny Access Group..

Comment: Then no loops are needed.

Answer (score 3):

The Notes object reference can be found locally in `help\help85_designer.nsf` on most servers.
The web version can be found here (with lots of example code): http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc%2Fr_domino_Database.html

Here's some pseudo code:

I've made the assumption you're initialised the NotesSession object already.

1. Open `names.nsf` on the server and assign this to a `NotesDatabase` object.
2. Get the view `DenyLists` and assign this to a `NotesView` object.
3. Iterate through the view assign each new document to a `NotesDocument` object.
4. The NptesItem you want to get from the Deny Access Group document is Members, and it contains a list of users or nested groups.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in @PanuHaaramo's comment, your code is an infinite loop. If there is only ever going to be one Group document in the DenyLists view, then the while loop is unnecessary so just get rid of it.  If there might be more than one, then keep the while loop but add fDoc=view.getNextDocument(fDoc) just before the closing }.

Panu is also correct that you are really making it harder on yourself than it needs to be.  Instead of using getItems() and looping through the results, you can just use getItemValue("Members"), which will return a Vector of Strings.

Also, if the environment where you intend to run your code may be using nested groups in the Deny Access list, then you will need to write additional code to test each String to see if it is a user or a group -- and also code to (recursively, since groups in the Deny List can also contain groups) access any nested groups and get their Members.

Comment: I made the corrections suggested by @Panu Haaramo and @ Richard Schwartz.Am able to retrieve the users from Deny group.Thank you guys.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could shed some light on Notes Terminologies such as **Form**,**View**,**Items**.Having hard time understanding them..

Comment: @farhansheik018 it helps to remember that Notes is a document/object orientated database or in modern parlance NoSQL. Views/Collections contain many Forms (Documents). A Form has many Items (fields).

Comment: It is important not to confuse a Form and a Document.  They are different things. The basic unit of storage in a database is called a note. There are design notes and data notes.  A Form is a design note.  It contains visual and programming elements that are used to display a document, including Fields.  A Document is a data note. It contains items.  One of the Items has the reserved name 'Form', and it refers to the Form that is used to display the Document.  The Items in the Document are typically displayed through Fields on the Form. Formulas and code on the Form determine how that happens.

Comment: And that's as much as I can put in one comment. There are many good books covering the basics of Notes and Domino, and this blog entry contains the full set of chapters of Bob Balaban's old but still useful book that is specifically about programming Notes with Java.  http://www.bobzblog.com/tuxedoguy.nsf/dx/programming-domino-with-java-final-flush